# How to import typescript file into script tag

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, dom

What I am trying to do is import an object from my typescript file into a script tag

This is what I am trying to do

```
<div id="app-root"></div>
<script>
import {config} from '../config.ts';

let script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=${config.GOOGLE_MAPS_KEY}`;

document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0].parentNode.appendChild(script);

</script>
```

I'm not sure if this is possible, but my react app is being rendered in #app-root and I am trying to handle my API key from my config. When I run this nothing happens, but If I add the static value instead it seems to work.

What I expect to happen is by passing the variable in to the script src, the script will execute successfully.

Comment: 1. its not possible
2. you can pass the variable as an environment variable, and have it compiled into the index template at run time (dev environment) or build time (prod environment). please consult CRA docs for more info

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible to read a ts file in script tag (at least without first compiling it to js).

What you can do, however, is to use environment variables instead, and let react-scripts compile it into your template as it already does everytime you start the dev server or run the build.

start here:

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables

First, create an env file called `.env` at the root of our project

Next, lets add our environment variable to this file:

```
REACT_APP_GOOGLE_MAPS_KEY=<your key>
```

Finally, let's modify index.html to reference our environment variable:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=%REACT_APP_GOOGLE_MAPS_KEY%"></script>
```

As a final thought, instead of going to all this trouble, you could instead include your google maps dependency where needed in the preferred react way: by using a react plugin. Check this out. it will take care of loading/unloading the api for you, and you can pass your key in from config when you load the api:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-google-maps/api

Answer (score 1):

The typescript files need to be compiled/converted to JS (to a .js file) in order to be used from the browser.

You can compile your TS file online here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play
and copy the output in .js

or

Install it via the command line (assuming you are on Windows)

```
npm install typescript // add -g if you want to install it globally
cd intoYourFolder // change directory to the folder where you have the .ts file
tsc *.ts // this will compile all typescript files in the directory
tsc yourFile.ts // this will compile only a specific file
```